# Problemas com a função lme com variáveis aninhadas (any(notIntX <- !apply(X, 2, const))

Tags: r, modelagem, lme4

Estou tentando ajustar um modelo de efeitos mistos em que eu tenho covariáveis que estão aninhadas (VarX5 | VarX6)  e são consideradas de efeitos fixos.

No entanto, estou tentando ajustar os dados e a seguinte mensagem aparece:

```
library(nlme)
library(lme4)

dados$VarCat=as.factor(dados$VarCat)
dados$VarX5=as.factor(dados$VarX5)
dados$VarX6=as.factor(dados$VarX6)

model <- lme(log(Resp)~log(VarX1)+log(VarX2)+(VarX3)+(VarX4)+VarX5|VarX6 ,random = ~1|VarCat, 
                 dados, method="REML")

Error in if (any(notIntX <- !apply(X, 2, const))) { : 
  valor ausente onde TRUE/FALSE necessário
```

Comment: Você já testou fazendo a limpeza de campos vazios?

Comment: @lmonferrari não existem campos vazios..

Comment: Estou votando para fechar a pergunta porque os dados necessários para reproduzir o problema foram removidos na última edição (e não adianta reverter, pois o link não funciona mais), o que faz com que a pergunta não atenda aos critérios de [um exemplo mínimo reproduzível em R](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/825/100416).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não está especificando as variáveis categóricas da maneira apropriada. Na `nlme:lme` elas ficam fora da fórmula, na opção `random`. Na `lme4:lmer` elas vão diretamente na fórmula, mas delimitadas por parênteses.

[redacted]

```
model <- nlme::lme(
  log(Resp) ~ log(VarX1) + log(VarX2) + VarX3 + VarX4,
  random = ~ VarCat | VarX5:VarX6,
  data = dados)

model <- lme4::lmer(
  log(Resp) ~ log(VarX1) + log(VarX2) + VarX3 + VarX4 + (VarCat | VarX5:VarX6),
  data = dados)
```

O operador `:` é um exemplo, estou assumindo que quer o efeito condicional. Para efeito cruzado, use `/`. Cheque os detalhes para `formula` na ajuda da `lmer` para diferentes especificações.

Comment: Obrigado @Carlos Eduardo Lagosta, no entanto, considerando que VarX5 e VarX6 estão aninhadas e são de efeitos fixos, se eu considerar dentro da função random que é para efeitos aleatórios estaria correto mesmo assim? ou seja ```random = ~ VarCat | VarX5/VarX6``` ,assim você diz??

Comment: Não, nesse caso, não. Eu supus que queria assim por ter convertido para fator e usado o operador "|". Este texto talvez te ajude: https://rpsychologist.com/r-guide-longitudinal-lme-lmer#three-level-models

Comment: Muito obrigado @Carlos Eduardo Lagosta. Mas ainda não consegui solucionar ..

Comment: Se o código roda mas a dificuldade é com a especificação do modelo, o [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) é mais indicado para buscar ajuda.